# Create an application for double click terminal command

Tags: command-line, doubleclick

I am a newbie.

I have .h5 files. I can convert them to .png files by executing "h5topng filename.h5" command in terminal. It creates "filename.png" file in the same folder. However, I want to do this conversion just by double clicking the .h5 files. I did it a long time ago and now I forgot how I did it. I searched for the forums for two days but I couldn't find how to do it.

I have two ubuntu installed computers (one has Ubuntu 14 and other has Ubuntu 16). One with Ubuntu 14 has that double clicking property. In that computer, I right click a .h5 file and open "properties" then select the "open with" tab. Here, I can see an application named "h5topng" as a default application.

Also, when I search "h5topng" in the computer with Ubuntu 14, it finds it in application but cannot open it or cannot show where it is installed.

One last thing, I am not sure but I remember something like that I can do this in Ubuntu 10, however, I should use another program or something like that in Ubuntu 14. As I said before, I am not sure about it.